# VSCode Keybindings: Commands vs. Command Ids?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

From my understanding, when inside of the [keyboard shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor), the bold commands represent commands that are available in the command palette, while the light commands represent command ids. Is that accurate? And if so...

The command `Insert Snippet` is available from the command palette. This opens up the snippets menu. But if you search for this command from the keyboard shortcuts editor, it brings up a command id, which is *not* the same command. The `Insert Snippet` command has the same functionality as the `editor.action.showSnippets` command id. But when you search for this command id, it does not show the `Insert Snippet` command in bold above it.

This is the only command that I've come across so far that doesn't seem to align with what I thought the bold/light text meant. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my understanding of bold and light commands was accurate.

There are two explanations for what is going on with `showSnippets` and `insertSnippet`:

- `editor.action.showSnippets` is an old command that still exists for compatibility.
- The new command, `editor.action.insertSnippet` is not showing because it accepts arguments. And commands that accept arguments, but do not have any rules in `keybindings.json` where that command is declared with arguments, will not show in the keyboard shortcuts UI editor.

Additional information found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79404) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80214).

And for those reading this and still trying to figure out which command to use to show the snippet menu, the answer is `editor.action.insertSnippet`. [As Alex noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56825067/4500152), executing `editor.action.insertSnippet` without args will show the snippet menu (as opposed to directly inserting a specific snippet).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe executing `editor.action.insertSnippet` without `args` just calls `editor.action.showSnippets`?

#### Shows menu

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+r",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
}
```

#### Inserts snippet

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+r",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "text"
    }
}
```

> Edit: Although, it's a bit weird that `editor.action.insertSnippet` is missing from Keybindings GUI when you have 0 user-defined snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to search for a command id seen in the Command Palette with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)

> ### [Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/3ce66fcd1caf64e15337e31e4ca39bce6ceb9ed3/release-notes/v1_52.md#keyboard-shortcuts-editor)
>
> We've added several improvements to the Keyboard Shortcuts editor in this milestone.
>
> **You can now configure a keybinding for a command from the Command Palette**.
>
> [image: Configure keybinding for a command from the Command Palette -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/configure-keybinding.gif]
> <sup>(Theme: [GitHub Light](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.github-vscode-theme))</sup>
>
> Plus, You can add several keybindings to a command from the Keyboard Shortcuts editor.
>
> [image: Add multiple keybindings -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/add-keybinding.png]
> <sup>(Theme: [GitHub Light](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.github-vscode-theme))</sup>

Comment: The words `snippet` or `insert` with `snippet` or `show` with `snippet` still do not show up in the Command Palette as of today's Insider Build.  So you still have to use the `Keyboard Shortcuts` search to find these commands.

Comment: @Mark OK, so this answer would not apply to the specific case presented by the OP. I will leave the answer here, as it would apply to other commands (available in the Command Palette)